# How can I see the current pytest configuration?

Tags: python, pytest

pytest gathers configuration settings from [various files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html) and command-line [options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#command-line-flags), but there doesn't appear to be a command-line option to show pytest's current settings, and I can't work out how to easily interrogate pytest for this info. `pytest --help` (or `pytest -h`) shows what the available options are but doesn't show their current values.

I've tried running pytest with `PYTEST_DEBUG` set (e.g. `$ env PYTEST_DEBUG=1 pytest --setup-only`): This generates a huge quantity of debug info but it doesn't appear to include the configuration settings, or at least not in a digestible format.

I see that there is a [`Config`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#config) object but I can't work out how to interrogate it to write a small program to output its content (I think it needs higher-level pytest-fu than I possess); I think this object may be the right place to look, assuming there isn't a command-line option to display the current settings that I've missed.

Comment: are you looking for the options passed in at the command line or the files?

Comment: @Lucas - I'd like to know what options/settings are currently in effect, so a combination of the options set by configuration files and those on the command-line, but just getting those from configuration files would be almost as good.

Comment: I left a couple ideas in an answer, let me know if this is along the lines of what you're looking for. I don't see a mechanism to print all config in effect but the answer I wrote will show you most of it-albeit with a little custom coding.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @Lucas Roberts answer I've taken a closer look at pytest's `pytestconfig` fixture which has various interesting attributes, particularly `option` (also `known_args_namespace` with similar contents). So if I understand `pytestconfig` correctly, a rough-and-ready solution to print the currently-in-effect options would be,

```
# test_sample.py
import pytest
import os

def test_answer(pytestconfig):
    for item_name in dir(pytestconfig.option):
        if not item_name.startswith('_'):
            print(f'{item_name}: {getattr(pytestconfig.option,item_name)}')
    assert 0  # to see what was printed
```

then run this as Lucas suggests with pytest (here with `-vv` for verbosity 2 for example),

```
$ pytest -vv test_sample.py
...
verbose: 2
version: False
xmlpath: None
==================== 1 failed in 0.10s ===================
$
```

Answer (score 4):

After looking through the pytest docs, there doesn't appear to be a direct way to enumerate all the config options automatically. Here are some ways to get at the config values though so hopefully these are helpful.

If you have a specific unit test and know particular values there is an example in the pytest docs that [show how](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html#request-example) to diagnose if those values are set.

Also, the config [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-configfile) describe the config file search and precedence.
Configuration settings come from several places for pytest, including cmd line options, ini files, and env variables.

The arguments to `pytestconfig` are the parts of `Config` and are described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.config.Config) in the documentation.

```
import pytest
import os

def test_answer(pytestconfig):
    if pytestconfig.getoption("verbose") > 0:
        print("verbose")
    print(pytestconfig.inipath)
    print(pytestconfig.invocation_params.args)
    print(os.getenv('PYTEST_ADDOPTS', None))
    print(pytestconfig.getini('addopts'))
    assert 0  # to see what was printed
```

Now if I run this in my directory with `pytest test_sample.py` (no cmd line arguments).
The contents of `test_sample.py` are given above.
The contents of the `pytest.ini` file are

```
[pytest]
addopts = -vq
```

and the `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` is not set I see:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/rlucas/Desktop/pytest.ini
('test_sample.py',)
None
['-vq']
================================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================================
FAILED test_sample.py::test_answer - assert 0
```

and using a different call of `pytest test_sample.py --verbose` you'll see

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
verbose
/Users/rlucas/Desktop/pytest.ini
('test_sample.py', '--verbose')
None
['-vq']
================================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================================
```

Here I'm abbreviating the output somewhat to the relevant info (e.g. I'm not showing the test failure info). If you don't have direct access to the filesystem where the unit tests are running you can always read in the file found in `pytestconfig.inipath` and print the contents to stdout.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you: You inspired me to explore the `pytestconfig` fixture which gets me a fair way to the answer, I'll post that separately as an unpolished answer